# mysql - get all columns of min(primary key) row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to join/add all columns of the `MIN(files.file_id)` row to this query rather than just returning the value of `MIN(files.file_id)` by itself as `first_file_id`.

`file_id` is an auto inc primary key.

Table `files` has file_id, user_id, filename, and timestamp columns.

I searched and it seems like this is possible by joining a temporary table that selects the columns from the row with `MIN(files.file_id)`, but can't get anything to work.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT 
        accounts.account_id,
        accounts.account_username,
        accounts.account_password,
        computers.computer_id,
        users.user_id,
        MIN(files.file_id) as first_file_id
    FROM accounts
    LEFT JOIN computers
        on computers.account_id = accounts.account_id
    LEFT JOIN users
        on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id
    LEFT JOIN files
        on files.user_id = users.user_id
    WHERE
        accounts.account_id = :account_id and
        computers.computer_name = :computer_name and
        users.username = :username
");

//bindings (test values)
$stmt->bindValue(':account_id', 1);
$stmt->bindValue(':computer_name', 'COMPUTER_2');
$stmt->bindValue(':username', 'jenny');
//execute
$stmt->execute();

//result (can only be one or none)
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**EDIT:**

This link has something similar to what I 'think' I need [link here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Join/Selectothercolumnsfromrowscontainingaminimumormaximumvalueistouseajoin.htm) and shows creating a temporary table with the rows info.

After viewing @Abhik Chakraborty response it got me thinking.  I removed the min and just added selects to the columns I want from `files` and it works.  Why... because I am only returning one result (fetch) and the join for `files` is joining the first row in that table that matches the other conditions.  Which in this case would be the row with the lowest file_id for that user since file_id is an auto inc primary key.

Can I make the assumption that I will ALWAYS get the lowest file_id row in `files` because of that?  That was the whole reason I was using `MIN(files.file_id)` in the first place, but now I am wondering if it is even necessary since it is an auto inc primary key.  This also assumes that I am not passing any ORDER BY conditions in my statement below as well.  I would still feel safer 'knowing' the right row will always be returned.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT 
        accounts.account_id,
        accounts.account_username,
        accounts.account_password,
        computers.computer_id,
        users.user_id,
        files.file_id,
            files.filename,
            files.timestamp
    FROM accounts
    LEFT JOIN computers
        on computers.account_id = accounts.account_id
    LEFT JOIN users
        on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id
    LEFT JOIN files
        on files.user_id = users.user_id
    WHERE
        accounts.account_id = :account_id and
        computers.computer_name = :computer_name and
        users.username = :username
");
```

Comment: are you getting only one first_file_id column in result??

Comment: My query works as shown, but yes, for now I am only 'adding' the first_file_id to the result.  I need the rest of the columns in its row returned as well.

Comment: consider providing the DDL and sample data along with desired output. May be on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I thought I could get away without it, but I'll set a fiddle up later.  Basically, I want to include all the columns from `files` where `files.file_id` is the smallest.  Right now I just include that column only... I need the rest of the columns in its row as well.

Comment: i see in that case you will need pivot table for join, let me try setting an example in fiddle for u.

Comment: You can just add the column names in the select list like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1be43/5 , I dont think you will need pivot table.

Comment: Luckily this question is asked (and even correctly answered) EVERY SINGLE DAY in SO. [other respondents may wish to familiarise themselves with those answers because, right now, they're not making any sense]

Comment: Can you elaborate @Strawberry ? I made some edits to my OP...

Comment: See the manual (uncorrelated subqueries are usually fastest): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Okay, this is very similar to the link I found originally and thought I needed to do, but I can't get it working with the current structure of my query.

Comment: Why not just use `order by files.fil_id asc limit 1`?